# Why is Session Callback function not invoked?

Tags: next.js, oauth-2.0, prisma, next-auth

I'm using nextauth for authentication, however when I login using the credential provider, it doesn't call/invoke the session callback. When I console log, I'm seeing the `userModified` object and the token object from JWT callback, but nothing is being console.log in the session callback and the session is not being created  and returned nor saved to the database.

However when I use google sign in, the session object is being invoked:

```
import NextAuth, { type NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcryptjs from "bcryptjs";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email";
// Prisma adapter for NextAuth, optional and can be removed
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";

import { env } from "../../../env/server.mjs";
import { prisma } from "../../../server/db/client";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // Include user.id on session
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, user , token }) {
      console.log('session ',session)
      console.log('user ', user)
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.id = user.id;
      }
      return {
        ...session,
        user
      };
    },
    async jwt({token , user}) {
      console.log('user is ',user)
      console.log('token is ', token)
      return token
    }
  },
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name : "credentials",
     credentials : {
        email : {label : 'Email', name : 'email', type : 'email'},
        password : {label : 'Password', name: 'password',type : 'password'}
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if(!credentials){
          return null
        }

        const { email, password } = credentials

        if(!email || !password) {
          return null
        }
        const userExists = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where : {
            email : credentials.email
          }
        }) 
        if (!userExists || !userExists.hashedPassword) {
          return null
        }  
      
        const isPasswordValid =  await bcryptjs.compare(password,userExists.hashedPassword)
        if(!isPasswordValid) {
          return null
        }
        const user = {
          id : userExists.id,
          email : userExists.email,
          isRegistered : userExists.isRegistered
        }
        console.log('user modified', user)
        return user
      }
    })
   
    // ...add more providers here
  ], 
  session:{ strategy: "database", }
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Here is the Session in schema.prisma:

```
model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

I expect user to be able to log in using their email and password through the `CredentialsProvider`. This involves the validation of provided credentials, including email and password.

The `authorize` function in the `CredentialsProvider` will then validate user credentials and return an object representing the authenticated user, which should includes :

```
 id : userExists.id,
 email : userExists.email,
 isRegistered : userExists.isRegistered
```

After a successful login with credentials, I want the jwt callback will be invoked which I see happening by the console.log. This callback logs the token and user data and should return the JWT token data.

This is not happening:

I then expect the session callback to be invoked. This callback modifies the session by adding the user.id property based on the user data received from the authorize function. It should return the modified session object with the user property. Then update the Session Table in the database

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, adding the secret key solved it for me.
`export default NextAuth({ secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET, providers: [...] })`

Comment: Same issue here, adding the nextauth_secret does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was facing was that I forgot to add the Session provider.

In the layout.tsx i added.

```
 <SessionProvider>
    {children}
 </SessionProvider>
```